# silverstripe groupby subpages by first letter alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, group-by, silverstripe

Silverstripe: I want to have my menus to have its list sorted and grouped by alphabetically. I have followed every step in [this documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/grouping-dataobjectsets) in using the GroupBy method her and to no avail.
Basically I want my subpages to appear as follows in the menu:

- B

  - Blog
- C

  - CMS Workflow
  - Custom Translations
- D

  - Database Plumber
  - ...

What is actually happening after following doing what is in the documentation is that i get an empty list, basically the $GroupedModules.GroupedBy(TitleFirstLetter) is not working.

The thing I think I may be missing here, is the creating of the Module class, I don't know where to create it, should it exist in the Page.php? 
Also, should be named Module?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked to shows how to do a group list of dataobjects (Module in their example). You want do a grouped list of pages, so you need to alter the code a little to fit your needs.

**Page.php**

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    // ...

    public function getTitleFirstLetter() {
        return $this->Title[0];
    }

    public function getGroupedChildren() {
        return GroupedList::create($this->Children()->sort('Title'));
    }

}
```

**Your template**

```
<% loop $GroupedChildren.GroupedBy(TitleFirstLetter) %>
    <h3>$TitleFirstLetter</h3>
    <ul>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li>$Title</li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know how to write the code for return GroupedList::create($this->Children()->sort('Title')); Works great, thanks a lot!